# Can someone please explain the purpose of .val("-") in the statement?

Tags: jquery

Can someone please explain the purpose of .val("-") in the statement?

Are we assigning the change event to dropdowns where value="-" in the following code? and what is the purpose of adding $tbApplications in the change function?

```js
$tbApplications = $("#tbApplications");

$("select", $tbApplications).val("-").on("change", function () {
 .....
});
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%" id="tblApplications">
   <tbody id="tbApplications">
      <tr id="trApplication_10147658" data-applicationid="10147658">
         <td class="tcenter" data-applicationid="10147658" data-reviewerid="87848165" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<strong>Name:</strong> Hachem, Ramsey<br><strong>Institution:</strong> Washington University<br><strong>Title:</strong> Isolation of Pseudomonas aeruginosa from Respiratory Specimens after Lung Transplantation and the Development of Chronic Lung Allograft Dysfunction" data-original-title="" title="" style="width: 50px; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="optRole_87848165_10147658" data-originalrole="18430" data-oprid="2013738" data-applicationid="10147658" data-reviewerid="87848165">
               <option value="-">-</option>
               <option value="18417">B</option>
               <option value="18414">1</option>
            </select>
         </td>        
      </tr>
      <tr id="trApplication_10147470" data-applicationid="10147470">
         <td class="tcenter" data-applicationid="10147470" data-reviewerid="87848165" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<strong>Name:</strong> Morrell, Eric<br><strong>Institution:</strong> University of Washington<br><strong>Title:</strong> Identifying Lung and Plasma Molecular Determinants for CLAD after Respiratory Viral Infection" data-original-title="" title="" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="optRole_87848165_10147470" data-originalrole="18432" data-oprid="2070118" data-applicationid="10147470" data-reviewerid="87848165">
               <option value="-">-</option>
               <option value="18417">B</option>
               <option value="18414">1</option>
            </select>
         </td>        
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: **$("select", $tbApplications)** is applying the change listener and the val change to ALL selects and the **#tbApplications** select. The val("-") just changes the select's default value to that of -. Combining them is just chaining them instead of having separate calls.

Comment: How does it gets all dropwdowns under tbApplications, don't we need to say $("select", $tbApplications select).val("-").on("change", function () {
 .....
});

Comment: I missed the ID object for tbApplications. You don't actually need that part, it can be removed. Since the first one is **select**, it covers ALL selects no matter where they are.

Comment: @imvain2 that's... incorrect. The id bit limits the selection of the first selector to elements within the element with that id.... In this case, the table.

Comment: .val does what .val does, and .on does what .on does.  the fact that they're being used together doesn't change that, they are unrelated.

Comment: How does the code know to get all the #tbApplications select?

Comment: That's what `$("select", $tbApplications)` means. It's short for `$tbApplications.find("select")`

Comment: @Barmar so the code is only looking for all dropdowns under $tbApplications, it is not looking for dropdowns outside of $tbApplications. Right

Comment: Yes, that's what `find()` does -- it finds all the elements matching a selector within the element that you called it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery documentation we can use $() with following parameter

**jQuery( selector [, context ] )**

**selector**
A string containing a selector expression

**context**
A DOM Element, Document, jQuery or selector to use as context

**Selector Context**
By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted like so:

```
$( "div.foo" ).click(function() {
  $( "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
});
```

When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional class.

Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so

```
$( "span", this )
```

is equivalent to `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery implements a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), which means that methods that aren't used specifically to look up a value return the object(s) they were called on. This allows you to chain methods together to perform multiple operations on the same elements. So

```
$("select", $tbApplications).val("-").on("change", function () {
 .....
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
let temp = $("select", $tbApplications);
temp.val('-');
temp.on("change", function () {
 .....
});
```

`temp` is the collection of all `select` elements inside `#tbApplications`. This sets all their values to `-`, and then adds a `change` listener to all of them.

The second argument to `$()` is the context in which to search for the selector in the first argument. `$(selector, context)` is equivalent to `context.find(selector)` or `$(context).find(selector)` depending on whether `context` is a jQuery object or something else.